# Install multiple packages simultaneously

Tags: python, macos, homebrew

I am brew_installing the following packages

```
cmds = ['brew install ghostscript',
 'brew install imagemagick',
 'brew install libmagic',
 'pip install sphinx']
 for cmd in cmds:
     os.system(cmd)
```

The command runs one by one.
How can run the four commands at same time?

Comment: You can try `brew install ghostscript,imagemagick,libmagic`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`brew` lets you install multiple formulae, if you separate them by a space.

Specify your formulae as a list;

```
formulae = ['ghostscript', 'imagemagik', ...]
```

Now, join those list elements with `str.join` and pass it to `os.system` -

```
import os
os.system("brew install {}".format(" ".join(formulae)))
```

However, this doesn't help with the `pip` command. Fortunately for us, `pip` doesn't need to be called via `os.system`. Import the module and call `pip.main`.

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'sphinx'])
```

This would still mean running two commands, but two is better than four.

Answer (score 0):

To make the last suggestion in Coldspeed's answer clearer:

```
import pip

for each in ["ghostscript","imagemagick","libmagic","sphinx"]: 
    pip.main(['install', each])
```